# Код работает не так, как нужно

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Нужно чтобы массив заполнился случайными числами в функции и программа вывела эти числа на экран. Но результат некорректный: выводит 00E11564. Как исправить?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//----------- Заполнение генератором случайных значений-------------

void RndArray(int *mass1, const int N, int &a, int &b){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        // диапазон случайных  значений от a до b

        mass1[i] = a + rand() % (b - a + 1);
    }

}
int main() {
    const int n=10;
    int a, b;
    int mass1[n];
    RndArray(mass1, n, a, b);
    cout << RndArray << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У вас в `std::cout` выводится адрес функции RndArray: `cout << RndArray << endl;`

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan а как вывести значение?

Comment: Примерно так: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { cout << mass1[i] << " "; }`

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Мне нельзя использовать в функциях вывод, такое условие задания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
cout << RndArray << endl;
```

на

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << mass1[i] << "  ";
```

Кроме того, не забудьте указать значения для `a` и `b`, а то у вас будет выводиться не пойми что...

Кроме того, совсем не нужно передавать `int` по ссылке - зачем? [Вот так](https://ideone.com/2AVsSj) вполне работоспособно.